# Changing Keyboard to Include "<-"

Tags: keyboard, r

How would I change a key on my keyboard to print "<-", for R?  I understand how to change a key to either "less" or "minus" in the keyboard files, but how would I change a key to include both?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this wasn't my problem.  I would like to know how specifically to make one key return multiple characters.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Any single key on the keyboard can only correspond to a single key press and release event of any key.